# Does try-catch share the same scoping block?

Tags: c#, try-catch, scope

I have a try-catch sequence.

```
try 
{
    int tryCatchVar = 0
    ...other code...
}
catch
{
    if (tryCatchVar != 0) return;
}
```

I declared and assigned a variable in the try block. Normally a variable's scope is the block it was declared in as well as all blocks nested within it. However, because of the strong relational aspect of try-catch, I am wondering if the variable declared in try is in scope for catch?

If not, then I guess I would want to do the following:

```
int tryCatchVar

try
{
    tryCatchVar = 0
    ...other code...
}
catch
{
    if (tryCatchVar != 0) return;
}
```

Would that work?

---

Reasoning:

I have two parameters that may throw exceptions. However, due to the limitations of my application (which are immutable at this point) I can only log user error messages to one specific string. I'm thinking of implementing two try-catch sequences. If either/both are tripped, they would generate an internal log stored in tryCatch. Then, depending on the value of tryCatch I would generate a new error message.

Comment: TRY IT AND SEE.

Comment: @Selman22 et al. Questions are asked on Stack Exchange site to stimulate discussion about the problem. Of course I could try it and see, but, like the answers below prove, I asked the question for the constructive feedback it generated. Consider un-down-voting.

Comment: @GrantWinney I have two parameters that may throw exceptions. However, due to the limitations of my application (which are immutable at this point) I can only log user error messages to one specific string. I'm thinking of implementing two try-catch sequences. If either/both are tripped, they would generate an internal log stored in tryCatch. Then, depending on the value of tryCatch I would generate a new error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, because of the strong relational aspect of try-catch, I am wondering if the variable declared in try is in scope for catch?

You can test this easily for yourself, but the answer is no.

(Second part)

> Would that work?

Again, you can test this easily for yourself, but the answer is no - because it won't be definitely assigned. You can fix it easily though:

```
int tryCatchVar = 0;

try
{
    ...other code...
}
catch
{
    if (tryCatchVar != 0) return;
}
```

(Of course I'd strongly recommend against catching *all* exceptions in this manner. Use *targeted* catch blocks, and it's very rarely a good idea to throw away the exception without at least logging it.)

Answer (score 4):

The general rule of thumb is that curly brackets define a scope. So whatever code you are looking at, the following is always true, regardless of what type of statement you are dealing with:

```
{
    int x;
}
{
    // x is now out of scope
}
```

However, the variable will be in scope as long and the block hasn't ended, even if a new block has started, so the case below illustrates a variable still in scope:

```
{
    int x;
    {
        //x is still in scope
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The scopes are different. You'd have to use code like this:

```
int tryCatchVar = 0; // or some other value

try
{
    tryCatchVar = 1;
    ...other code...
}
catch
{
    if (tryCatchVar != 0) return;
}
```

The reason, in simple terms, is that anything in the `try` may or may not actually run before the `catch`, based on if and when an exception is thrown, so the compiler can't assume that anything there has actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

No; the `catch` is not within the `try`'s scope.